# Installing HDFS/HBase client library

Tags: java, hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

How do I install the package org.apache.hadoop and org.apache.hbase in my windows machine so that I can develop client(s) for connecting to an existing HBase cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download hadoop dump from http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#Download

Direct link to download 1.2 version - http://mirror.tcpdiag.net/apache/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz (you can also choose other mirrors and versions).Extract jars from various folders (lib, etc.,.) and add to eclipse build path.

Download hbase from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hbase/

Direct link for 0.94 version- http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/hbase/stable/hbase-0.94.12.tar.gz .Extract jars from various folders (lib, etc.,.) and add to eclipse build path.

Comment: Thanks Eswar. I resolved some more dependencies and able to move past.

Comment: Glad it helped you,please post about other dependencies that you resolved coz others reading this question may find it useful.

Comment: Sure.The other dependencies I resolved are: commons-lang-2.6 commons-logging-1.1.3 slf4j-1.7.5

Comment: However I am not able to connect to HBase from Windows. I asked this as a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061206/not-able-to-connect-to-hbase-from-windows Could you please have a look?

Comment: Ok I got it. I did not have core-site.xml. Also I had to solve one more depenency: protobuf-java-2.4.0a. After all this I am able to connect and insert data.